# crear un componente text en storybook reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy creando un componente de texto que contenga un `Paragraph`, `Header`, `SubHeader` que cada uno de estos tiene diferente tamaño de texto pero el header tiene 5 diferentes tipo de texto, a que me refiero: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo lo estoy haciendo con la libreria de tailwind y no se como pasarle las propiedades de 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 en el story mi codigo esta asi:

index.jsx:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

function size() {
    return {
        1: 'text-4xl',
        2: 'text-3xl',
        3: 'text-2xl',
        4: 'text-xl',
        5: 'text-lg',
    }
}
export default function Text({ size, children }) {
  return <div className={size}> {children} </div >
}

Text.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string
}

export default Text;
```

story.js:

```
import React from "react"
import Text, { size } from "./index"
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react"

storiesOf('Text', module)
    .add('Paraghraph', () => (
        <Text textType='paraghraph'>
            hola muy bien
        </Text>
    ))
    .add('Head', () => (
        <Text 
           textType='Head'
           size={[1]}
           >
            funtion 2
        </Text>
    ))
```

repito, lo que necesito es que mi componente head tenga 5 tamaños de texto con las clases de tailwind pero debo pasarlas como un objeto que al poner 5 esta tenga el tamaño de text-4xl

Comment: Edité mi respuesta pues me dí cuenta después, espero te sirva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás casi, sólo te falta, en tu archivo `story.js`, usar la función `size()` que importas desde `index.jsx` para de pasarle los props a tu componente `Text`.

Para eso primero tienes que asegurarte que estás exportando la función `size()` (pues en lo que subiste, no lo haces)

```
export function size() {
    ...
```

Y luego de eso podrás ocuparla para entregar el prop correcto en el story

```
import React from "react"
import Text, { size } from "./index"
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react"

storiesOf('Text', module)
    .add('Paraghraph', () => (
        <Text textType='paraghraph'>
            hola muy bien
        </Text>
    ))
    .add('Head', () => (
        <Text 
           textType='Head'
           size={size()[1]}
           >
            funtion 2
        </Text>
    ))
```

===========================================================================

Totalmente aparte pero te sugiero una manera mas idiomática para tu componente

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

function textSize(num) {
    const sizes = {
        1: 'text-4xl',
        2: 'text-3xl',
        3: 'text-2xl',
        4: 'text-xl',
        5: 'text-lg',
    }
    return sizes[num] || 'text-lg' // si el numero no existe, entrega un valor por defecto
}
const Text = ({ size, children }) => {
  return <div className={textSize(size)}> {children} </div >
}

Text.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.number
}
Text.defaultProps = {
  size: 1 // me aseguro que haya algo si no me pasan nada
}

export default Text;
```

Así tu componente Text sólo recibe el número necesario, sin necesidad de tener que exportar e importar tu función helper. Además agregué buenas prácticas de componentes como `defaultProps`

```
import React from "react"
import Text from "./index" // ya no hay import de size
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react"

storiesOf('Text', module)
    .add('Paraghraph', () => (
        <Text textType='paraghraph'>
            hola muy bien
        </Text>
    ))
    .add('Head', () => (
        <Text 
           textType='Head'
           size={1} // 
           >
            funtion 2
        </Text>
    ))
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono, me dio un error pero era el de quitar el export default el ultimo de index.jsx

Comment: Se me pasó también el doble export default, sólo deja uno por archivo. Modifiqué el componente para que sólo tenga uno. Ojo que es necesario que el export default esté al final, sino estarás exportando antes de la definicion de `propTypes` y `defaultProps`

Comment: aahh ok, yo lo edite tu pregunta quitando eso, no se si lo dañe haha mil disculpas :(

Comment: No hay problema jajaj lo dejé como estaba. Saludos!

Comment: hola, una pregunta, le puedo quitar el storiesOf ya que me dicen que es de la version vieja y que ya no se ocupa, como podria hacer eso?